# Instagram Client Side Login using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, reactjs, instagram

I'm reposting this as i didn't get any answer. i have tried all from my side so Need help with instagram client side login with username and password.

On instagram login screen I have username and password field and they have somekind of reactdataid field.

```
<input class="-cx-PRIVATE-LoginForm__inputField -cx-PRIVATE-TextInput__root" aria-describedby="errorAlert" aria-required="true" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" id="lfFieldInputUsername" maxlength="30" name="username" placeholder="Enter your username" tabindex="1" type="text" value="" data-reactid=".0.1.0.1.0.1.0.1.1.1">

<input class="-cx-PRIVATE-LoginForm__inputField -cx-PRIVATE-TextInput__root" aria-describedby="errorAlert" aria-required="true" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" id="lfFieldInputPassword" name="password" placeholder="Enter your password" tabindex="2" type="password" value="" data-reactid=".0.1.0.1.0.1.0.1.2.2">
```

when I do the following

```
document.getElementById('lfFieldInputUsername').value='xxxx'
document.getElementById('lfFieldInputPassword').value='xxxx';
```

and press login it doesn't allow me to login. I see values get updated in fields but it doesn't submit those in the login form which it submits and gives error. How I can update those fields automatically to login. 
Does react work in any different way kindly help. Chrome autofill also works what it does differently than what I did from chrome console?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Instagram auto login using client javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32830479/instagram-auto-login-using-client-javascript)

Comment: What's the context, you've given very little information or code to go on.

Comment: Question is I'm using chrome console to update the username and password on the instagram login page. but even I update the username and password using javascript it doesn't take those input so need any info why its not taking internally those values? something special about React?